# Firebase generate circle thumbnail fail with code 1

Tags: node.js, firebase, imagemagick, google-cloud-functions

I tried to use ImageMagick to convert Image upload from My App to Firebase by Cloud Functions.

```
return spawn("convert", [
    tempFilePath,
    "(",
    "-size", 
    dim + "x" + dim, 
    "xc:black",
    "-fill",
    "white",
    "-draw",
    "\"circle",
    dim2 + "," + dim2,
    dim2 + "," + dim1+"\"",
    ")",
    "-alpha",
    "off",
    "-gravity",
    "center",
    "-compose",
    "copy_opacity",
    "-composite",
    "-crop",
    dim+"x"+dim+"+0+0",
    "-thumbnail",
    "300x300>",
    tempFilePathPNG
  ]);
```

with `dim` and `dim2` is my specific dimension. But when I use that function, the error appear and I don't know how. You can check the image below.

```
`convert /tmp/7eee6327-8b7a-41f8-a1a2-19bbc3f297c2.jpg ( -size 2592x2592 xc:black -fill white -draw "circle 1296,1296 1296,2591" ) -alpha off -gravity center -compose copy_opacity -composite -crop 2592x2592+0+0 -thumbnail 300x300> /tmp/7eee6327-8b7a-41f8-a1a2-19bbc3f297c2.png` failed with code 1
```

I also try others generate like only `resize` and `draw image` and it success. But this code above is fail always. Please help me.
[image]

Comment: Your path contains - and may be confusing Imagemagick. Try enclosing the path in " " I recommend starting with something simple - a plain circle with fixed values and when that works expand on it.

Comment: There must be spaces on either side of parentheses. Does your code provide that spacing?

Comment: I run this code in https://imagemagick.online and I have what I expect. I also think that because that file path but when I run the simple code like generate thumbnail, it's fine.

Comment: You need to escape the parenthesis. Use `"\("` instead of `"("`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution!!!
I convert spawn to exec in child promise like below and it works. I also put the double escape near by bracket to make it work. But I still want to use spawn.

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        exec("convert "+tempFilePath+" \\( -size "+dim+"x"+dim+" xc:black -fill white -draw \"circle "+dim2+","+dim2+" "+dim2+","+dim1+"\" \\) -alpha off -gravity center -compose copy_opacity -composite -crop "+dim+"x"+dim+"+0+0 -thumbnail 300x300 "+tempFilePathPNG,(error,stdout,stderr)=>{
          if(error){
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
            return;
          }
          resolve();
        })
      })
```

Comment: It works using `spawn()` by escaping the parenthesis only once instead of twice: `await spawn('montage', args, {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr'] })` where `args = [ ..... , '\( thumb.png -colorspace Gray \)', .....]`

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer due to insufficient carma:

convert expects filename as the last argument, or "-" to use standard output.
In your case the last argument is 300x300, so convert would fail with something like:
convert: missing an image filename `300x300'

Try replacing "300x300>" with "300x300 - >"